# Criterion C header not found on macOS

Tags: c, macos, gcc, c-criterion

I have the requirement to install [Criterion](https://github.com/snaipe/criterion) (which is a testing framework for C) on my laptop running macOS. I use Homebrew daily so I thought it will be be easy to just run the [brew command](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/criterion):

```bash
brew install criterion
```

But, every time I try to run a C file with the criterion header with GCC or CLANG, it just can't find Criterion, although it is installed. (I use the [simple sample](https://github.com/Snaipe/Criterion/blob/bleeding/samples/simple.c) from the official Criterion repo)

```c
#include <criterion/criterion.h>

Test(misc, failing) {
    cr_assert(0);
}

Test(misc, passing) {
    cr_assert(1);
}
```

```bash
$ gcc -o test test.c -lcriterion
test.c:1:10: fatal error: 'criterion/criterion.h' file not found
#include <criterion/criterion.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

```bash
$ brew install criterion
Warning: criterion 2.4.1_1 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 2.4.1_1, run:
  brew reinstall criterion
```

I'm struggling with that for almost 2 days and I'm out of ideas...
I even tried to install gcc via Homebrew but it doesn't seem to work either

```bash
$ /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/12.2.0/bin/gcc-12 -o test test.c -lcriterion
test.c:1:10: fatal error: criterion/criterion.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <criterion/criterion.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I use the Apple clang version 14.0.0 for gcc and the homebrew gcc uses gcc 12.2.0. I run a MacBook Air M1 2020 with Ventura 13.1 (22C65)

Comment: Where does `brew` install its packages? I assume it's in a non-standard location, so you have to add flags to tell the compiler where to find header files, and also to the linker to tell it where to find the libraries?

Comment: You need to provide the path of the header files (criterion.h) to gcc using -I flag.
E.g. `gcc -o test test.c -lcriterion -I /usr/include/` if `criterion.h` is in `/usr/include/criterion` directory

Comment: I'd guess it's in /opt/homebrew/include, and you'll probably have to specify `-I/opt/homebrew/include -L/opt/homebrew/lib`. I don't know homebrew well enough to know if it's supposed to set that up for you automatically e.g. in the INCLUDE and LIBS environment vars.

Comment: "I use the Apple clang version 14.0.0 for gcc and the homebrew gcc uses gcc 12.2.0." - why different versions? You're probably OK with C but that can be painful with C++.

Comment: add `-I/usr/local/Cellar` to build process. check `brew ls --verbose criterion`.

Comment: Thanks! This was that simple... just needed to specified the path of the header files like said @Rup... thanks everyone, and merry christmas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar problem and as @Rup pointed out, the solution is to pass Homebrew's `lib` and `include` folder, which contain the binaries and header files respectively, to the C Compiler/Linker.

Makefile example:

```makefile
test: test.c
    gcc $< -o $@ -I/opt/homebrew/include -L/opt/homebrew/lib -lcriterion
```

Or just run in the terminal:

```bash
gcc -o test test.c -I/opt/homebrew/include -L/opt/homebrew/lib -lcriterion
```